# Setting summernote to be italicised by default

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, summernote

So I have a series of summernote inputs that I want to be italicised by default. I only want the italics button option, so I have removed all others.

[Image of multiple summernote entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnbTz.png)

Html generating these:

```
<div style="width:250px;">
     <div class="summernote" id="RTE_@Model.ST_ID">
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Answer, htmlAttributes: new { id = "Answer_" + @Model.ST_ID})
      </div>
</div>
```

--

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.summernote').summernote({
          toolbar: [
               ['style', ['italic']],
          ],
          onChange: function (e) {
               // Do some event
               // Update the HiddenFor element with the formatted text
          }
     });
});
```

The location of the italics button is set by CSS.

I want to set all of the inputs to be italicised by default.

I tried:

```
$('.summernote').summernote('italic');
```

As per [Summernote - Deep Dive](http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#font-style-api)

It sets the first input, but not any of the others.

Then I tried

```
$('.summernote').each(function() {
     $(this).summernote('italic');
}
```

And it just doesn't do anything...

I also tried:

```
var elements = document.GetElementsByClassName('summernote');
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    $(elements[i]).summernote('italic');
}
```

No luck.

Any ideas??

Comment: Do you have some html that we could have a look at?

Comment: @NeilDocherty I have updated my initial post with the html.

Comment: Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOReyE).

Comment: @Ricky - Thank you, but was it meant to help my problem?

Comment: @DavidDerry yes it was, but I had to go, just providing a starting point.

Comment: @Ricky No worries, thanks. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: @David Derry Sure, probably not ideal but will keep you going. Will add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there does not seem to be any other option than doing a manual click to the italic button in the toolbar:

```
  $(".note-btn-italic").trigger("click");
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.summernote').summernote({
    toolbar: [
      ['style', ['italic']],
    ]
  });
  $(".note-btn-italic").trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.js"></script>

<div style="width:250px;">
  <div class="summernote" id="RTE_@Model.ST_ID"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works well for one summernote entry, but when I add multiple it breaks
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/worpga